# Echo bash function time in minutes and seconds

Tags: bash

```
somefunc(){
    time (
        sleep 90
    )
}

somefunc
```

Is there any way to just get minutes.seconds in a variable so I can do something like

```
somefunc(){
    blah=$(time (
        sleep 90
    ))
    echo "Somefunc finished in $blah"
}

somefunc

Somefunc finished in 1m30s
```

## EDIT

I have the following now:

```
timeit() { 
    blah="$(TIMEFORMAT='%lU'; time ( $1 $2 $3 ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
    a=$?
    echo "$2 $3 job finished in $blah"
    return $a   
}

timeit /home/blah/script.sh $var1 $var2
```

In my script I end up calling anywhere from 1 to 30 of this function at the same time in subshells, which runs the script I am using in it, but I am getting the wrong times out of it. they all say 0m0.002s or something like that, only fractions of a second, no seconds or minutes.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from `time` goes to **STDERR** not **STDOUT**. In order to capture it's value to a variable, you need to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

somefunc() {
    blah="$(TIMEFORMAT='%lU'; time ( $1 ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
    echo "Somefunc finished in $blah"
}

somefunc bleh
```

You can play with the `TIMEFORMAT` to get the output you desire.

#### In Action:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

somefunc() {  
    blah="$(TIMEFORMAT='%lU'; time ( $1 ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
    echo "Somefunc finished in $blah"
}

somefunc ls
```

```
$ bash script.sh
    Somefunc finished in 0m0.001s
```

Comment: N.B.: this code is really bash specific and does not work with either zsh's implementation of `time` or `/usr/bin/time` (which is ok, given the title of the question, but I guess it was good to say)

Comment: Thanks for the confirming that @zmo. Yes, I tested it on `bash`. I can't say for `zsh` shell. `:)`

Comment: This works for me, but it seems I am getting the exit code of time command.  Is there a way to get the exit code of the $1 from the time command as well and set it as a variable?

Comment: Not quite sure. If you do `time foo` and `echo $?`, what do you get?

Comment: I figured out the return code issue I had, but now I am seeing that I am not getting the right times out of it. A command that runs for 5 minutes will say something like 0m0.032s. Thoughts?  Also, where can I find a list of TIMEFORMAT options?